# Getting error when changing a dropdown box for second time

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

So I have two dropdown boxes and the first dropdown box response is being generated at loading of the page and the second dropdown responce is generated on changing of the first dropdown response

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <select name="country_city" class="inputbox" required ng-model="frm.country_city" ng-change="state_city()">
        <option ng-repeat="country in country_city track by $index" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select name="state_city" class="inputbox" required ng-model="frm.state_city">
        <option ng-repeat="state in state_city track by $index" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.state_city = function() {
    console.log("in state city");
    $scope.frm.country_city;
    $http.get(url, {
        params: {
            action: 'get_state_city',
            country_id: $scope.frm.country_city
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config, jsonp) {
        $scope.state_city= data;
        console.log($scope.state_city);
    });
};
```

The problem is that when I change the response of the first dropdown box for a second time it gives me an error. The images are to help. The third image shows the error

[image]

[image]

[image]

The images show the selection of india country and Maharastra state as response but when selecting USA just to change the response  give the error

Comment: wow, you have 8000+ unread emails. Don't put image like this.

Comment: are you sure, the html is properly mapped with the controller in which you have the function?

Comment: @sreehari thik so because it works proper for first time

Comment: @sreehari s  what else you suggest

Comment: Can you check $scope.state_city = function() {
    console.log("in state city");} putting an console.log alone in your function and see if its getting called multiple times... remove other code in state_city

Comment: @Thalaivar i just tried your suggestion it works every time i change the response but then where do you suggest the error could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `scope` `function` name and `scope variable name` are same:

```
$scope.state_city = function() {
    console.log("in state city");
    $scope.frm.country_city;
    $http.get(url, {
        params: {
            action: 'get_state_city',
            country_id: $scope.frm.country_city
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config, jsonp) {
        $scope.state_city= data; => Issue is here
        console.log($scope.state_city);
    });
};
```

You are creating a function `$scope.state_city()` and then inside your success function you are doing this `$scope.state_city= data;`, from the next time your `state_city` become a `variable` with `response data` and no more a `function`.

Comment: yup thanks @Thalaivar for your responce that was realy ignorant of me

Comment: @SnehalGongle: That's fine... it happens happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
 $scope.change_state_city = function() {
            $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                action: 'get_state_city',
                country_id: $scope.frm.country_city
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config, jsonp) {
            $scope.state_city= data;
            console.log($scope.state_city);
        });
    };
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="country_city" class="inputbox" required ng-model="frm.country_city" ng-change="change_state_city()">
        <option ng-repeat="country in country_city track by $index" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select name="state_city" class="inputbox" required ng-model="frm.state_city">
        <option ng-repeat="state in state_city track by $index" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```